# Send an int to a paired Bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I managed to create a ListView, search for devices and show them, on click connect to the selected device, but now I want to know how to send from one phone to the other one just an int or a boolean or something like this.
It's a little game, there is a winner and a loser - so I want to compare two variables and check who won, then display it.

My code so far:

Searching

```
bluetooth.startDiscovery();
  textview.setText("Searching, Make sure other device is available");
  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
  registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

Displaying in a ListView

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            Log.i("BT", device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
        }
    }
};
      @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Pairing the devices

```
    private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Log.d("pairDevice()", "Start Pairing...");
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
        Log.d("pairDevice()", "Pairing finished.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("pairDevice()", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

It works pretty well, both devices are paired.
Do I need a client and a server to transfer ints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code from the android SDK: [BluetoothChat](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/25b6aed7b2e01ce7bdc0dfa1a79eaf009ad178fe/samples/BluetoothChat)

The key is to use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) on both sides of the connection that both listens for incoming messages and sends outgoing messages. Then all your [Activity](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html) has to worry about is interacting with the user, and telling the service to send the appropriate messages.

```
//METHOD FROM ACTIVITY
private void sendMessage(String message) {
    // Check that we're actually connected before trying anything
    if (mChatService.getState() != BluetoothChatService.STATE_CONNECTED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.not_connected, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    // Check that there's actually something to send
    if (message.length() > 0) {
        // Get the message bytes and tell the BluetoothChatService to write
        byte[] send = message.getBytes();
        mChatService.write(send);
        // Reset out string buffer to zero and clear the edit text field
        mOutStringBuffer.setLength(0);
        mOutEditText.setText(mOutStringBuffer);
    }
}

//METHOD FROM SERVICE
public void write(byte[] out) {
    // Create temporary object
    ConnectedThread r;
    // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
    synchronized (this) {
        if (mState != STATE_CONNECTED) return;
        r = mConnectedThread;
    }
    // Perform the write unsynchronized
    r.write(out);
}
```

Comment: So I can just use sendMessage(int XXX) ?

Comment: @David, no, please check out the link and view the source of the sample in its entirety. I've also edited my answer, you may want to re-read it.